# What'll happen if log2(len(list)) is not an integer while doing binary search? How many operations will it have to do?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search, logarithm

I'm trying to figure out how many operations binary search would have to do if it were given an array whose's length when "logged" with base 2 would not result in a whole number.

I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ceiled to the immediate superior integer. You can't do "0.2" operations, it's one or zero, and you need to do "something more"... So a whole operation.

For an array of 5 elements, your binary search is (worst case):

```
(O = non tested, - = rejected, X = value to search)

X O O O O
    ^ Start here.   Op. #1
X O - - -
  ^ New pivot       Op. #2
X - - - -
^ Found             Op. #3
```

As you see, you get exactly the same number of operations that a worst case for 8 elements, the next power of two. And `log2(5)=2.32...`, ceiled to 3, and that's what the worst case shown too.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right, since the number of comparisons for 8 elements is 4, and for 5 elements is 3. The correct formula is not ceil(log2(n)), but floor(log2(n))+1.

Comment: @PaulHankin Right. It doesn't change the _base_ answer: you ceil to the immediate superior integer, because you can't do a fraction of an operation. But it's true that the validity domain for (log2(n)) is open on upper limit.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment, but it seems to me that the number of operations (comparisons) is floor(log2(n)) + 1 and not ceil(log2(n)).  The number of comparisons for 8 elements is 4, the number of comparisons for 5 elements is not the same -- it's 3.

Comment: The base question was "how many operations are done when log2(n) isn't an integer". And it's "ceil(log2(n))", because you can't do a partial operation. But the generic formula is, indeed, with a floor.

Answer (score 0):

There's three cases in binary search: the pivot matches, it's too large, or it's too small. If your list is length n, and the pivot is at index floor(n/2), the new problem has size 0, floor((n-1)/2), ceil((n-1)/2).

The worst-case is when you choose the ceil((n-1)/2) case each time. This gives the recurrence relation for the worst-case number of comparisons for a list of size n as:

```
C(0) = 0
C(n) = 1 + C(ceil((n-1)/2)) = 1 + C(floor(n/2))
```

A moment's thought shows that C(n) is the length of n in binary digits,
which for n>0 is floor(log_2(n)) + 1.